# React JS Context API with functional component is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am working on a React JS project that uses the context API, React hooks and the functional components. Now. I am trying to create a context provider and trying to change the state if its from the child component. But it is not working as expected. This is what I have done so far.

I have created context provider component with the following definition.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext({ currentLan: 'en' });

class LangContextProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    currentLan: 'en'
  }

  switchLang = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentLan: this.state.currentLan == 'it'? 'en': 'it',
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <Provider value={this.state}>{this.props.children}</Provider>
  }
}

export { LangContextProvider, Consumer as LangContextConsumer };
```

Pay attention to the `switchLang` function, because I am trying to call it from the child component to update the state.

This is my child component with a button that updates the state of the provider.

```
const SwitchLangButton = () => {

   return (
       <LangContextConsumer>
          {langContext => (
              <button onClick=() => { langContext.switchLang() }>Switch lang</button>)
          }  
       </LangContextConsumer>
   )
}
```

As you can see, I am calling `switchLang` function when the button is click to switch language.

I wrap my app with the provider as follow.

```
<LangContextProvider>
    <React.Fragment>
        <App />
    </React.Fragment>
</LangContextProvider>
```

When I click on the button, I got the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: langContext.switchLang is not a function
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the switchLang function:

```
<Provider value={{currentLan: this.state.currentLan, switchLang}}>{this.props.children}</Provider>
```